# Find and replace opening and closing HTML tag with specific class using Regex

Tags: html, regex, replace, phpstorm

I want to change this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
...
</div>
```

to this:

```
<x-panel>
...
</x-panel>
```

I am using `Replace in Path` feature.

What I typed on `Search` box (this one seems to match correctly):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">[^>]*>[^{]*</div>
```

What I typed on `Replace` box:

```
<x-panel>$1</x-panel>
```

It is giving me this error:

```
You have entered malformed replacement string $1
```

[image: You have entered malformed replacement string $1]

Comment: You can try SSR (Structural Search and Replace) for this instead of RegEx: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html . Examples for HTML: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#examples-for-html-and-xml

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example:

https://regex101.com/r/UQrpTV/1

First group is > `(<div.*.panel-default\"\>)`

second > `(.*)`

third closing tag > `(<\/div>)`

and you substitute second group > `<x-panel>$2</x-panel>`

[image]

I don't have phpstorm but also note that you have to enable global, multiline, insensitive case and don't match new line to have it like this working in your editor I think