# Search and replace text within an html element

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I have a project with about a thousand instances of:

```
<div class="panel-heading"><h4>Title</h4></div>
```

Is there a way with PhpStorm or a tool the would allow me to find all html blocks that start with `<div class="panel-heading">` and remove all instances of `<h4>` and `</h4>` within that block.

I want this:

```
<div class="panel-heading"><h4>Title</h4></div>
```

to become this:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
```

Only where I have 'Title', it will be different with the 1000 or so instances.

Comment: You can use SSR (Structural Search and Replace) for this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html . Examples for HTML: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#examples-for-html-and-xml

Comment: P.S. You can also use RegEx for this .. as long as such pattern is simple and repeatable (e.g. and you do not have other tags instead/in addition to `h4` etc). **P.P.S** Kind of similar recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63440465/783119